# How to use Eclipse with Php5.6

Tags: php, eclipse, laravel

As you can see in this photo I have problems with eclipse while programming with laravel framework. The problem is eclipse is looking for php5.3 code but laravel and my local server uses php5.6. So how can i upgrade my eclipse for Php5.6? [image: laravel and eclipse]

Comment: What version of Eclipse do you use? Latest should support PHP5.6

Comment: @YasenZhelev Version: 3.8.1 I'm on ubuntu

Comment: This is a Juno version released 2012. I would suggest upgrading to a more recent version that support latest PHP versions. Try the latest official release Luna Eclipse ver. 4.4

Comment: @YasenZhelev I really do not know how to do it on Ubuntu. Any idea?

Comment: Google it :) follow instructions from here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse%3F or here: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-2.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Juno version released 2012. I would suggest upgrading to a more recent version that support latest PHP versions. Try the latest official release Luna Eclipse ver. 4.4.

Follow the instructions here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse%3F
or here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse%3F

Answer (score -2):

Isn't eclipse dead already?

Everyone now uses PhpStorm (a fantastic IDE), or NetBeans if you don't wish to pay for the licence.

Comment: I do not know if we are able to use PhpStorm full on Ubuntu?

Comment: Sure you can! Download a trial version and try it out! You wont regret it :)

Comment: And you will have to pay for it after the trial. Some users can not afford it. I use PHPStorm and I would recommend it too, but in case you are looking for free IDE Eclipse is still an option. BTW your answer is not really an answer of the question been asked.

Comment: Thats why I mentioned Netbeans, so my answer us still valid. In last 5 years I have not heard any dev that woild use eclipse...